# Initialize components with an internal ID

Tags: generics, components, vhdl

I should create a structure (entity "A") composed of N components (entities "B"). Each component has several inputs and outputs and  an internal signal ID (must be static), that identificates the component from 0 to N-1. Each component perform some operation based on ID. My problem is how to attribuite a static ID to each component at initialization time (during the port mapping). Obviously the components are "created" in for..generate loop, because N could be generic.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the loop identifier in the `for .. generate` as ID for the instantiated components?  Btw. it would be a great help in understanding the question if you included the relevant code.

Comment: I know that inserting code is very usefull, but I was very tired when written the question. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a generic for your components, assign it the loop index of the generate, and, internally, assign the generic to the signal:

```
entity insider is
  generic(id: natural);
  port(
    ...
  );
end entity insider;

architecture arc of insider is
  signal s: natural;
begin
  ...
  s <= id;
  ...
end architecture arc;

...

architecture arc of outsider is
  ...
begin
  ...
  g: for i in 1 to 10 generate
    i: entity work.insider
      generic map(id => i)
      port map(
        ...
      );
  end generate g;
  ...
end architecture arc;
```

Comment: Thank you! And sorry if the question was without an example code, I was very tired when I wrote it.